# Call a function automatically when data changes?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a list of points defined as follows:

```
private List<Point> points = new List<Point>();
```

that I want to draw on a given canvas by the following function:

```
private void draw_all_points_on_canvas(Canvas canvas_name, List<Point> points);
```

My question is that: **how can I achieve the goal that this drawing function will be called automatically when the data `points` change**?

---

**P.S.:** This question seems to be very similar to make the data to be a `ObservableCollection` (`ObservableCollection<Point> points`) which, however, will not directly work here as I cannot use `canvas_name.ItemsSource = points;` as I need also to define how these points are drawn on the canvas in the drawing function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need a `ObservableCollection` and hook up its `CollectionChanged` event, which is how wpf gets notified when there is a change in data.

```
private ObservableCollection<Point> points = new ObservableCollection<Point>();

points.CollectionChanged += points_CollectionChanged;//Subscribe event

void collection_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   //Handle it below respectively
    switch (e.Action)
    {
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
            break;
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
            break;
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
            break;
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move:
            break;
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
           break;
    }            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can still use an `ObservableCollection<Point>`:

```
_points = new ObservableCollection<Point>();
_points.CollectionChanged += (o, e) => 
    draw_all_points_on_canvas(canvas_name, _points);
```

As a side note, it it possible to use data binding to draw points onto a `Canvas`:

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Ellipse Fill="Black"
                        Width="1"
                        Height="1" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left"
                    Value="{Binding X}" />
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top"
                    Value="{Binding Y}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

Then use `ItemsSource = points` and voilà! Note this way may not perform as well as drawing using a `DrawingContext`, and if you have a **lot** of points you should prefer the latter. Otherwise this method has a lot of other advantages:

- You render your data in XAML
- You can use data binding and triggers
- Each item is a fully-fledged control, which means it can have tooltips, respond to mouse, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`ObservableCollection<T>` would work here, because it define the `CollectionChanged` event...

Subscribe to that event - and it would be raised automatically when the data had changed (I'm assuming the `Point` is immutable).

Comment: [Point is Mutable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.point%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: For some reason I remembered otherwise... 

anyway, you cannot be notified about a point being changed. what you can do - is wrap the point with your own type, and that type would have event for that (you can implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`)